# Running selenium (chromedriver) in a terminal window?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

How can i run a python script using selenium (chromedriver) in an terminal window (without X forwarding).

The results/interactions with the website don't need to be shown. Par example filling a form scheduled by a cronjob.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [PyVirtualDisplay](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyVirtualDisplay) with [Xvfb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb)

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

# now Chrome will run in a virtual display. 
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
```